# Get CIDR block for each AZ in an AWS region using Terraform functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Using Terraform variables, how can I output a CIDR block for each availability zone in a region?

I can get close, but I'm obviously missing something with the cidrsubnet function.

```
[for az in data.aws_availability_zones.available.names : cidrsubnet("10.0.0.0/16", 8, 101)]
```

My current output is -

```json
[
  "10.0.101.0/24",
  "10.0.101.0/24",
  "10.0.101.0/24",
  "10.0.101.0/24"
]
```

What I desire is -

```json
[
  "10.0.101.0/24",
  "10.0.102.0/24",
  "10.0.103.0/24",
  "10.0.104.0/24"
]
```

#### Example Code

```
data "aws_ami" "app_ami" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["bitnami-tomcat-*-x86_64-hvm-ebs-nami"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["979382823631"] # Bitnami
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "my-vpc"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  azs            = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  public_subnets = [for az in data.aws_availability_zones.available.names : cidrsubnet("10.0.0.0/16", 8, 101)]

  enable_nat_gateway = true
}

resource "aws_instance" "blog" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.app_ami.id
  instance_type = "t3.nano"

  vpc_security_group_ids = [module.blog_security_group.security_group_id]

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}

module "blog_security_group" {
  source      = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version     = "5.1.0"
  name        = "blog"
  description = "Allow HTTP and HTTPS from my IP in."

  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id

  ingress_rules       = ["http-80-tcp", "https-443-tcp"]
  ingress_cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  egress_rules       = ["all-all"]
  egress_cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tricky aspect of a design like this is that AWS availability zones are not inherently ordered, and the zones available to your account could potentially change over time in ways that might renumber previously-allocated subnets, which would be very disruptive.

To avoid such problems, a typical approach is to preallocate a subnet number to each possible availability zone letter, and then sparsely populate your address space with only the subnets corresponding to availability zones that are really available in your account. For example:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

locals {
  az_network_numbers = tomap({
    a = 101
    b = 102
    c = 103
    d = 104
    e = 105
    # (and so on for however many AZ letters you'd like to support)
  })
  available_zone_letters = tomap({
    for az in data.aws_availability_zones.available.names :
    az => regex("[a-z]$", az) # take only the final letter
  })
  available_zone_cidr_blocks = tomap({
    for az, k in local.available_zone_letters :
    az => cidrsubnet("10.0.0.0/16", 8, local.az_network_numbers[k])
  })
}
```

`local.available_zone_cidr_blocks` will then be a map from availability zone to generated CIDR prefix address, such as:

```
tomap({
  "us-east-1a" = "10.0.0.101/24"
  "us-east-1c" = "10.0.0.103/24"
  "us-east-1d" = "10.0.0.104/24"
})
```

Notice that in this example `us-east-1b` isn't available and so it's left `10.0.0.102/24` unassigned. If `us-east-1b` were to become available later then it could be allocated `10.0.0.102/24` without renumbering anything else. If `us-east-1c` were to become unavailable later then `10.0.0.103/24` would become vacant but `us-east-1d` would stay allocated to `"10.0.0.104/24"` rather than being reallocated to `"10.0.0.103/24"`, preventing disruption to objects in that availability zone.

Comment: Thanks, this approach makes sense and has done the trick. I'll update my question to show how I used your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a list depending on how many elements are present in `data.aws_availability_zones.available.names`, in which case you can use:

```
$ terraform console
> formatlist("10.0.10%v.0/24", range(1, length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)+1))
tolist([
  "10.0.101.0/24",
  "10.0.102.0/24",
  "10.0.103.0/24",
  "10.0.104.0/24",
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and it works for me using Terraform version 1.5.3

```
data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["YOUR-VPC-NAME"]
  }
}

# Selects all subnets
#data "aws_subnets" "example" {
#  filter {
#    name = "vpc-id"
#    # uses data source above
#    values = [data.aws_vpc.selected.id]
#  }
#}

data "aws_subnets" "example" {
  filter {
    name = "vpc-id"
    # uses data source above
    values = [data.aws_vpc.selected.id]
  }
  filter {
    # assumes you have Name tags populated on your subnets
    # replace Name tag values with your own 
    # or use any tag:value you have that clearly indicates what your public subnets are
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["public-subnet-a","public-subnet-b","public-subnet-c","public-subnet-d"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = { for index, subnetid in data.aws_subnets.example.ids : index => subnetid }
  id = each.value
}

output "subnet_cidr_blocks" {
  value = [for s in data.aws_subnet.example : s.cidr_block]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but would this not select all public and private subnets? I realise my question didn't specifically state public, but that is my intention.

Comment: yes it would select all subnets. In `data "aws_subnets" "example"` block another filter could be added to filter on private or public subnets based on Name tag with the assumptions your private & public subnets are clearly named in your VPC. I'll update my answer to show this.